# Magento2: How to get the text box value in paste event in ko template

Tags: magento2.2, php-7.1

I want to get the otp value after paste event.

```
 <div class="cod-enter-otp required enter-otp hidden mgt20 pmtd">
                <div class="field mrg0">
                    <label class="control-label label" for="otp">Enter OTP</label>
                    <div class="otp-control control">
                        <input type="text" name="otp" id="otp"  maxlength="6" class="input-text input-otp" data-bind="value:otp,disable:isDisabled,valueUpdate:'keyup,paste',event:{keyup:verifyOtp,paste:verifyOtp},hasFocus:isFocused">
                        <i class="bar"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

**In js:**

```
verifyOtp: function (value) { console.log(this.otp());
            var otp = this.otp(), self = this, payload;
            if (otp.length == 6) {}}
```

But not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show me what kinds of error you have got?

Comment: No error. Copied value not pasted in text box. I'm trying to get otp it returns undefined

Comment: Would you please share js function verifyOtp ?

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: otp() funtion ?

Comment: otp: ko.observable(),